# Standard Euclidean Metric on $\mathbb{R}^{k^2}$.

Tags: real-numbers

Does the standard euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{k^2}$ refer to
$$
\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i^2}\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i^2
$$

or does $\mathbb{R}^{k^2}$ have some other meaning, like $\mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: In typical notation $\mathbb{R}^k\times \mathbb{R}^k = \mathbb{R}^{2k}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{k^2} = \mathbb{R}^k\times \ldots \times \mathbb{R}^k$ ($k$ times) or $\mathbb{R} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{R}$ ($k^2$ times).

Comment: most common use is for square matrices, the (squared) norm is $\operatorname{trace} A^T A$

Comment: @Winther got it.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks